# Expected accuracy of the pet example using SSD model in TensorFlow object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using default pipeline configuration (ssd_inception_v2_pets.config) and pretrained inception v2 COCO model. In TensorBoard, the loss continues decreasing, but the average precision isn't getting any better. Has anyone done similar experiment using inception v2 for SSD? What's your experience?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the low mAP is due to [extreme low score threshold at non maximum suppression step](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v2_pets.config#L126). The result of such low threshold is that almost every image would produces more than 70 detections, while there's only one ground truth in each image. Changing this threshold to a more reasonable value -- 0.1 -- produces much better mAP plot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may have been bitten by this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2749
as I was.

Try updating & grabbing one of the new starting pretrained files, and seeing if your problem is resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, but I'm using SSD model, not mobile net.

Comment: I'm using SSD+mobilenet, you're using SSD+inception. There are many shared code blocks between the two, including the problematic Hard Example Miner most likely.